Rendering a jQuery component with React: How to write the useEffects?
We have a code stack with lots of legacy jQuery components. We're moving toward React, and one of the steps is wrapping jQuery with React.
However, managing the state of a non-React child component like this doesn't seem to be something that is commonly covered for useEffects. es-lint/exhaustive-deps doesn't like any of my solutions. I've reviewed https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/ and React docs, but I'm still not sure what the right answer is.
The naive function component looks like this:
const MyReactFunctionComponent = (props) => {
  const element = useRef(null);
  const [JQueryComp, setJQueryComp] = useState(null);

  const renderJQueryHelper = () => {
    // Not 1-1 props match, lot of transformation and helper functions
    const JQueryProps = { ...props };
    return new myJQueryComponent(JQueryProps, element.current);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // only heavy render on first mount
    setJQueryComp(renderJQueryHelper());
    return () => {
      JQueryComp.destroy();
    };
  }, []); // warn: missing deps 'JQueryComp' and 'renderJQueryHelper'
  
  // call update on every reRender, comp diffs the props itself.
  if (JQueryComp) {
    JQueryComp.update(props);
  }

  return <div ref={element} />;
};

In theory, I could move the entire helper inside the useEffect, but this turns into a mess very quickly and I'd like to avoid that. Following various guides, I arrived at this solution, with a useRef to store the useCallback.
  const renderJQueryHelper = useCallback(() => { ..., [props]);

  const helperRef = useRef(renderJQueryHelper);

  useEffect(() => {
    setJQueryComp(helperRef.current());
    ...

This works for helper functions, and I've already used this elsewhere. But it doesn't cover JQueryComp, which I need to be able to call destroy. It also doesn't handle cases where I do want to run the heavy render helper more often, like if the jQuery component crashes, or if anything else is more complicated. I feel like I must be missing something.
I'll include example implementation of JQueryComp, as well as how this looks in a class component where it seems much simpler.
const myJQueryComponent = (props, element) => {
  const $element = $(element);
  $element.addClass('my-JQuery-component');

  const initialize = () => {
    // lots of JQuery code here, attaching containers, event listeners, etc.
    // eventually renders other JQuery components
  };

  const render = () => {
    if ($element.children().length > 0) {
      $element.trigger('JQuery_COMP_UPDATE', props);
    } else {
      initialize();
    }
  };

  this.update = _.debounce((newProps) => {
    if (newProps.type !== props.type) {
      this.destroy();
    }

    if (!_.isEqual(newProps, props)) {
      props = newProps;
      render();
    }
  }, 100);

  this.destroy = () => {
    $element.trigger('JQuery_COMP_DESTROY').empty();
  };

  render();
};

class MyReactClassComponent extends React.Component {
  renderJQueryHelper() {
    // Not 1-1 props match, lot of transformation and helper functions
    const JQueryProps = {...props}
    return new myJQueryComponent(JQueryProps, this.element);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.JQueryComp = renderJQueryHelper();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!this.JQueryComp) {
      // JQuery comp crashed?
      this.JQueryComp = renderJQueryHelper
    }

    this.JQueryComp.update(this.props);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.JQueryComp) {
      this.JQueryComp.destroy();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={(element) => (this.element = element)} />;
  }
}


I think both your initial solution and your "arrived-at" solution are very close to being correct. I don't think the local state is necessary though, so I believe the myJQueryComponent component/object reference can be stored in another React ref.

Create a second React ref to hold a reference to a myJQueryComponent object.
Use a mounting (empty dependency array so effect runs exactly once) useEffect hook callback (analogous to a React class component's componentDidMount lifecycle method) to instantiate the myJQueryComponent and return a cleanup function (analogous to a class component's componentWillUnmount lifecycle method) to destroy the current myJQueryComponent object when the component unmounts.
Use a second useEffect hook to handle the component lifecycle where the props value changes over time and is used as a dependency to trigger updating the myJQueryComponent object (analogous to a class component's componentDidUpdate lifecycle method).

const MyReactFunctionComponent = (props) => {
  const elementRef = useRef(null);
  const jQueryCompRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const jQueryProps = { ...props };

    jQueryCompRef.current = new myJQueryComponent(
      JQueryProps,
      elementRef.current
    );

    return () => {
      jQueryCompRef.current.destroy();
    };
    // NOTE: mounting effect only
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    jQueryCompRef.current.update(props);
  }, [props]);
  
  return <div ref={element} />;
};

On the off-hand chance that the above doesn't quite work and React still needs a bit of a kick to know it should rerender the DOM is fully updated and repainted you can force a component rerender if necessary.
Example:
const useForceRerender = () => {
  const [, setState] = useState(false);

  // useCallback is used to memoize a stable callback
  return useCallback(() => setState(c => !c), []);
};

const MyReactFunctionComponent = (props) => {
  const elementRef = useRef(null);
  const jQueryCompRef = useRef();

  const forceRerender = useForceRerender();

  useEffect(() => {
    const jQueryProps = { ...props };

    jQueryCompRef.current = new myJQueryComponent(
      JQueryProps,
      elementRef.current
    );

    return () => {
      jQueryCompRef.current.destroy();
    };
    // NOTE: mounting effect only
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    jQueryCompRef.current.update(props);
    forceRerender();
  }, [forceRerender, props]);
  
  return <div ref={element} />;
};


Woah, are you really allowed to do things like this? Err, is rendering a jQuery component like this actually unusual enough that it merits breaking React rules like this? I was really told not to ignore exhausive-deps. I think I do understand switching to useRef in this case, we don't need the features of useState and its clear when I would use each, but useForceRerender feels like it could be a huge anti-pattern. Should you only use that in cases very similar to this one?

@IsaiahShiner What React rules are being broken here? Are you referring to the use of an empty dependency array to run the effect exactly once? The React-hooks linting rules are just the broadest set that generally produce the desired result, but what you pass in the dependency array controls when the effect fires. If you only want it to run once, then pass an empty array.

@IsaiahShiner Yes, I totally agree that using any sort of "force rerender" is a general React anti-pattern, but the ability to do so is useful in extreme edge-cases like this where you are directly working with a non-React library that does it's work outside the React framework. It's an "escape hatch", inspired by the old React class component's forceUpdate method. Jquery and React have rather orthogonal approaches to UI control/flow, they are like oil and water, so some "manual control" is sometimes necessary.

@IsaiahShiner The old legacy docs spell this out a bit better than the current docs, https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects, scroll down a bit to find a Note in a yellow box that clarifies this as a use case.

Yep yep, this makes a lot more sense. The React docs push steer users away from escape hatches because most users shouldn't use them. And they don't mention as much about jQuery or other libraries because there's so many cases. And good call on the older docs, I'm used to jumping to the new docs, but older can have a different perspective. I guess now I want to keep a toolkit of escape hatches and be clear about what React is thinking and exactly what breaking the rules really means. Thank you for the help!

@IsaiahShiner Welcome, happy to help. I hope my answer here helps resolve your question/issue.

I'll probably add my own answer in a bit to give clear context on exactly what I decided to do.

This is what I ended up with.
const elementRef = useRef(null);
const jQueryCompRef = useRef(null);

// This ends up being redeclared every render, but that's fine.
const jQueryProps = someComplexHelperFunction(props);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!jQueryCompRef.current && elementRef.current) {
    jQueryCompRef.current = new myJQueryComponent(jQueryProps, elementRef.current);
  }
  // Turns out, I do want this to run every frame. If the component crashes,
  // this will attempt to recreate it.
}, [jQueryProps]);

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    jQueryCompRef.current?.destroy();
  };
  // But, I only want to destroy it on unmount. Otherwise you get screen flashing.
}, []);

